# Rewrite urls in htaccess file - remove query string

Tags: apache

I have never edited the .htaccess file before so sorry for my awful attempt

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.site/index/%1 [R=302,L]
```

I am tryting to rewrite http://ex.com/shop/?s=sa to look like http://ex.com/shop/sa

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi, i have updated

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "\s/shop/\?s=(\w*)\s"` -> `RewriteRule ^ "http://example.site/shop/%1?" [R=302,L]`

Comment: Hi deaooshka I seem to get a 500 error with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `rewriterules` in shop directory and index.php is handling the data then try with below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
```