# Remove (now) unused query argument from rewritten URL

Tags: .htaccess

Can't seem to get this working, I want to rewrite some old query-driven URLs to a new format:

URL Before: http://www.example.com/blog/?lang=fr

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^&](\w+)=(\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

URL After: http://www.example.com/fr/blog/?lang=fr

Close, but no cigar!  I've tried a few SO solutions (i.e. [Rewrite urls in htaccess file - remove query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835160/rewrite-urls-in-htaccess-file-remove-query-string)) but I think that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QSD only works since version 2.4 of Apache. If you are using an older version, it works with :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^&](?:\w+)=(\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```